# Flutter ListTile splash/ripple effect not matching border

Tags: flutter

I have a ListTile in flutter but I cannot seem to figure out how to make the splash/ripple effect fit the border. My border is rounded, but the splash is just a normal rectangle with no round borders, as seen on the image below.

[ListTile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJoU.jpg)

Below is the code for the ListTile.

```
Ink(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius)),
    ),
    child: ListTile(
      title: text(title, 0.0),
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        color: primaryColor,
      ),
    )
)
```

Comment: Try to wrap your listtile in a card and remove the decoration property from the Ink, and style your card instead

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use InkWell:

```
InkWell(
    customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    onTap: () {},
    splashColor: Colors.red,
    child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Title"),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround `Ink` or `InkWell` with `ClipRRect` with border-radius value equal to
`BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius))`

Better, replace `Ink` with `InkWell` and set `borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(borderRadius))` which won't need clipping.

thus you can write

```
InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
    onTap: () {},
    splashColor: Colors.red,
    child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Title"),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the shape of the ListTile to the same shape as the parent widget.

```
ListTile(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  title: 'title',
  onTap: () {},
),
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this syntax over the highly upvoted accepted answer?

Comment: First of all because it does not require you too rap your list tile in another widget. Secondly you can also apply this shape globaly inside a theme.